# How to remove the margin of the view in the constraint layout when the anchor constraint is removed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-databinding

I have a constraint view as follows, the image of which is given below

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/SellerProfileContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:visibility="@{sellerFullName != null ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/Title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/Title"
            app:layout_goneMarginTop="24dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/SellerProfileImage"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:contentDescription="@{sellerProfileImageAccessibilityText}"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:visibility="@{sellerProfileImage != null ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
                android:src="@{sellerProfileImage}" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/SellerProfile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:contentDescription="@{sellerFullName}"
                android:text="@{sellerFullName.text}"
                android:visibility="@{sellerFullName != null ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/SellerProfileImage"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/SellerProfileImage"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/SellerProfileImage"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                tools:text="Seller Profile Name"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/SellerRatings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{sellerFeedbackPercent}"
                android:contentDescription="@{sellerFeedbackPercent}"
                android:textColor="@color/style_guide_neutral6"
                android:visibility="@{sellerFeedbackPercent != null ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/SellerProfile"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/SellerProfile"
                tools:text = "100% positive rating"/>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Constraint layout image]

I am trying implement the layout as follows:

1. If the `sellerProfileImage` is not null, then `sellerProfileImage` and `sellerProfile` should have a margin of 16dp between them.
2. If the `sellerProfileImage` is null, then `sellerProfile` should have zero margin between the parent (constraint layout) and itself.

I tried the following approach

1. For `sellerProfile`, I did the following `android:layout_marginStart="@{uxContent.sellerProfileImage != null ? @dimen/margin_16dp : @dimen/margin_0dp}"` where the `margin_16dp` and `margin_0dp` equals 16dp and 0dp respectively.

But when I compiled the code, I got the following error

```
Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.TextView android:layout_marginStart> that accepts parameter type 'float'

If a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.
```

How can I conditionally adjust the start margin of the layout depending on whether the seller profile is present or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to adjust the margins in your layout to make use of "gone" margins. See
[Margins when connected to a GONE widget](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#GoneMargin).

Here is a simplified version of your layout as an example:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/SellerProfileContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndtOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_goneMarginTop="24dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/SellerProfileImage"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SellerProfile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="sellerFullName"
        android:visibility="@{sellerFullName != null ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/SellerProfileImage"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/SellerProfileImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/SellerProfileImage"
        app:layout_goneMarginStart="0dp"
        tools:text="Seller Profile Name" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I made adjustments to the margins of the two widgets. The key change is setting `app:layout_goneMarginStart="0dp"` on the *TextView*. This will set the start margin to `0dp` when the image is `gone`.

[image]

and to `16dp` when the image is `visible`.

[image]

You should be able to accomplish this aspect of your layout without the use of data binding.